Ordering Y-axis labels in ggplot2 when using a leveled factor doesn't work
I'm using the following to generate a column plot of my data. But despite converting the variable Recommendations into a leveled factor, the Y-axis labels still are NOT ordered the way they are listed in the DATA.
Is there any other fix to order the Y-axis labels the way they are listed in the DATA?
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

DATA %>% mutate(Recommendations = factor(Recommendations, 
                                        levels = DATA$Recommendations),
                                        Recommendations = stringr::str_wrap(Recommendations, 30)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = Recommendations, x = `Number of Responses`)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(`Number of Responses`, "(", scales::percent(`Number of Responses` / sum(`Number of Responses`), accuracy = 1), ")")), hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1,
            size = 3, fontface=2)+
  theme_minimal(16) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_line(),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 9))

DATA <- structure(list(Recommendations = c("Criteria/guidance for authenticating transcripts", 
"Training on international schooling systems", "Interview/Schooling history templates", 
"Repository of international transcripts/previously reviewed courses annotated with grade and credit equivalency", 
"Course articulation agreements with specific countries", "Proficiency assessments in students’ home languages", 
"A professional learning community or community of practice for staff members who are responsible for evaluating credits earned outside of the U.S.", 
"Hiring an external expert or agency to evaluate transcripts", 
"Other"), `Number of Responses` = c(115, 81, 39, 88, 39, 55, 
58, 26, 9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 9L))


I was wrong. The issue is that you first have to use str_wrap. Then set the order of the levels. The way you do it you convert your factor back to a (wrapped) character.

@stefan, I actually did that too, still without success.

"Is there any other fix to order the Y-axis labels the way they are listed in the DATA?" Yes, there is: forcats::fct_inorder() changes the order of the levels by the order in which they first appear.

The issue is that you use str_wrap after converting to a factor. This way you are converting your factor to a (wrapped) character which gets ordered alphabetically. Switch both lines of code and instead of using Data$Recommendations use forcats::fct_inorder or levels = unique(Recommendations) (or use rev(unique(Recommendations))) to reverse the order) as I do below:
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

DATA %>%
  mutate(
    Recommendations = stringr::str_wrap(Recommendations, 30),
    Recommendations = factor(Recommendations, levels = unique(Recommendations)),
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Recommendations, x = `Number of Responses`)) +
  geom_col(fill = "steelblue") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(`Number of Responses`, "(", scales::percent(`Number of Responses` / sum(`Number of Responses`), accuracy = 1), ")")),
    hjust = 0, nudge_x = 1,
    size = 3, fontface = 2
  ) +
  theme_minimal(16) +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_line(),
    axis.text = element_text(size = 9)
  )



Thank you works great, asking this just in case, is there a way to get the columns closer to the y-axis?

Sure. This is because of the default expansion which you can remove or set to zero at the left using + scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, .05))
